# TypeError in discord.py command arguments

Tags: python, discord.py

Whenever an user runs `!clear` this error occurs, the command should be the base utility to clear the last `amount` messages

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\*****\Desktop\bot_discord.py", line 29, in clear
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
Command raised an exception: TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount: int=None): #Solved putting ": int=None" after "amount"
    if amount == "all":
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=10000000000000000000000000000000000)
        await ctx.send("Cleared the entire chat!")
        print("Cleared the chat!")
    else:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
        await ctx.send("Done!")
        print(f"Cleared {amount} messages!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is absolutely correct. But if you enter all as argument, it will not work. To fix this, You can use the following

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount: int=0, all:str = ""): 
    if all == "all":
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=10000000000000000000000000000000000)
        await ctx.send("Cleared the entire chat!")
        print("Cleared the chat!")
    else:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
        await ctx.send("Done!")
        print(f"Cleared {amount} messages!")
```

This will work, it doesn't has any required argument, and even if you type `!clear` it will not give an error. Best of luck with your bot. Cheers!

EDIT:
For anyone who didn't understand the error, it tells that you cannot set the limit as string. Because in the command above when you do `else` and your argument value is 'abc' it will give error that it cannot do integer functions on the string.